# Detect img src and then change it with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onchange, addeventlistener, src

This is my code:

```
var i;
var pic = document.getElementById('image');
var picSrc = pic.src;
var fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
pic.src = fullSrc;

document.getElementById('next').onmousedown = function () {
    i = 0;
            // it works up to here
    pic.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(event) {
        if (i == 0 && event.attrName == "src") {
        pic = document.getElementById('image');
        i = 1;   // this is to prevent endless loop
        picSrc = pic.src;
        fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
        pic.src = fullSrc;
        }
});
return true;
};
```

It should work on imgur's horizontal layout albums, and replace the low-res images with full-res ones, one image at a time (currently displayed image).
On click of the "next" button, a new image is displayed. However, the script does not load the next full-res image. It only works with the first image loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up your scope completely, invalidating the entire code after the first run. This should also pop up more than enough errors in your console. Reshuffle assignments to the right spot:

```
document.getElementById('next').onmousedown = function () {
    var i;
    var pic = document.getElementById('image');
    var picSrc = pic.src;
    var fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
    pic.src = fullSrc;
    pic.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(event) {
        if (i == 0 && event.attrName == "src") {
        pic = document.getElementById('image');
        i = 1;   // this is to prevent endless loop
        picSrc = pic.src;
        fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
        pic.src = fullSrc;
        }
});
return true;
};
```

Depending on how the page works specifically (I can't see without having a real world use case) you might have to reassign the entire mousedown event as well.

Comment: This does not work. Real world use case: try to load an imgur album, for example this one: http://imgur.com/a/DcH4L/layout/horizontal with this greasemonkey script installed: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/183438

Answer (score 0):

On every `mousedown` you are adding a new `DOMAttrModified` event listener.

Try arranging your code to something like following:

```
var pic = document.getElementById('image');
var i;

pic.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(event) {
        if (i == 0 && event.attrName == "src") {
        //pic = document.getElementById('image');
        i = 1;   // this is to prevent endless loop
        picSrc = pic.src;
        fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
        pic.src = fullSrc;
        i = 0;
    });

document.getElementById('next').onmousedown = function () {
    var picSrc = pic.src;
    var fullSrc = picSrc.split('h.jpg')[0] + '.jpg';
    pic.src = fullSrc;
});
```

You should also try using the `addEventListener` instead of `onmousedown`

Comment: I have moved the `addEventListener` out of the function so only one gets created. Newly loaded images still don't work, despite that the `pic.src` is correctly detected and changed.

Comment: This is because on mousedown on next, you are setting the the src to be the same except removing the last "h" character. In the ````onmousedown```` handler ````var picSrc = pic.src;```` needs to be set to new filename